# Tridion login issue

Tags: 2011, content-manager

We are having issue with Tridion login. Some user can't log in the system and it is keep asking for password. We are using active directory for authentication and the ID is fine. Other users have no issue. It seems it mostly affecting users which are using VPN (using the same login).
Has anybody encounter this issue? Is there a log within Tridion to show what is the issue with the login? If so, how can I turn on the log?

Update: I am able to trace to this error in windows security log, not sure why it is happening though.

```
An account failed to log on.
Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       xxxx
    Account Domain:     xxxxxxx

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     An Error occured during Logon.
    Status:         0xc000006d
    Sub Status:     0x0

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x0
    Caller Process Name:    -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   xxxxx-T430
    Source Network Address: 10.1.115.1
    Source Port:        64866

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      NtLmSsp 
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0

This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.

The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.

The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
    - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
    - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
    - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.
```

Comment: You can check in the Event Viewer on the content manager server for logs related to login failure. I have seen this issue before, but it's not necessarily a Tridion issue. It's possible over VPN, the company require to go thru a certain proxy, or use a fully qualified domain name in the URL

Comment: Thanks, Robert. It traces to this error in windows security events: An account failed to log on.
Subject:  Security ID:  NULL SID
 Account Name:  -
 Account Domain:  -
 Logon ID:  0x0
Logon Type:   3
Detailed Authentication Information:
 Logon Process:  NtLmSsp 
 Authentication Package: NTLM
 Transited Services: -
 Package Name (NTLM only): -
 Key Length:  0

Comment: Authentication is handled by IIS, so check its logs for details

Comment: Probabaly better move this to something like http://serverfault.com/, since it's only loosely related to Tridion (it's just IIS authentication failing, the fact that there is a Tridion web application inside that site, is not relevant)

Comment: It is not IIS authentication. We use LDAP authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is relating to a Windows patch for our domain controler. Our server team is working to roll back the patch. Hope that solves the problem.